# Celery - Django web app on Heroky with Celery worker process - how can I chase down this memory leak?

Tags: python, heroku, celery, django-celery

I'm running `heroku logs --ps celery --tail` and seeing the following:

```
Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
Process running mem=650M(127.1%)
```

`DEBUG` is set to False.

Celery version is 3.1.9

I have no idea how to chase down this memory leak.  The first step I took was to print out all Celery-related config settings, which are pasted below.  I'd be interested in other ideas about how to debug this.  Can I check how much memory is being used from within the Celery task itself?  Do I have to explicitly tell it to release memory?  Any other ideas?

Celery config settings:

```
{
    "CELERY_RESULT_DB_TABLENAMES": null,
    "BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS": {},
    "BROKER_USE_SSL": false,
    "CELERY_BROADCAST_QUEUE": "celeryctl",
    "CELERY_STORE_ERRORS_EVEN_IF_IGNORED": false,
    "CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES": true,
    "CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE": "celery",
    "CELERY_SEND_TASK_SENT_EVENT": false,
    "CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT": null,
    "CELERY_EVENT_QUEUE_EXPIRES": null,
    "CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE": "direct",
    "CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER": "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler",
    "CELERY_MAX_CACHED_RESULTS": 5000,
    "CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT": null,
    "CELERYD_POOL": "prefork",
    "CELERYD_AGENT": null,
    "CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND_OPTIONS": {},
    "BROKER_HEARTBEAT": null,
    "CELERY_RESULT_ENGINE_OPTIONS": null,
    "CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER": "json",
    "CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE_FILENAME": "celerybeat-schedule",
    "CELERY_REDIRECT_STDOUTS_LEVEL": "WARNING",
    "CELERY_IMPORTS": [],
    "CELERYD_TASK_LOG_FORMAT": "[%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s/%(processName)s] %(task_name)s[%(task_id)s]: %(message)s",
    "CELERY_SECURITY_CERTIFICATE": null,
    "CELERYD_LOG_COLOR": null,
    "CELERY_RESULT_EXCHANGE": "celeryresults",
    "CELERY_TRACK_STARTED": false,
    "CELERY_REDIS_PASSWORD": null,
    "BROKER_USER": null,
    "CELERY_COUCHBASE_BACKEND_SETTINGS": null,
    "CELERY_RESULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE": "direct",
    "CELERY_REDIS_DB": null,
    "CELERYD_TIMER_PRECISION": 1.0,
    "CELERY_REDIS_PORT": null,
    "BROKER_TRANSPORT": null,
    "CELERYMON_LOG_FILE": null,
    "CELERYD_CONCURRENCY": 0,
    "CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER": true,
    "BROKER_VHOST": null,
    "CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE": "celery",
    "CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY": "celery",
    "CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER": false,
    "CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT": null,
    "CELERY_WORKER_DIRECT": false,
    "CELERY_REDIS_HOST": null,
    "CELERY_QUEUE_HA_POLICY": null,
    "BROKER_PORT": null,
    "CELERYD_AUTORELOADER": "celery.worker.autoreload:Autoreloader",
    "BROKER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT": 4,
    "CELERY_ENABLE_REMOTE_CONTROL": true,
    "CELERY_RESULT_DB_SHORT_LIVED_SESSIONS": false,
    "CELERY_EVENT_SERIALIZER": "json",
    "CELERY_REDIS_MAX_CONNECTIONS": null,
    "CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND": null,
    "CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER": 4,
    "BROKER_PASSWORD": null,
    "CELERY_MONGODB_BACKEND_SETTINGS": null,
    "CELERY_EAGER_PROPAGATES_EXCEPTIONS": false,
    "CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT": false,
    "CELERYMON_LOG_LEVEL": "INFO",
    "CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS": false,
    "CELERY_TASK_PUBLISH_RETRY_POLICY": {
        "interval_start": 0,
        "interval_max": 1,
        "max_retries": 3,
        "interval_step": 0.2
    },
    "CELERY_SECURITY_KEY": null,
    "CELERY_BROADCAST_EXCHANGE_TYPE": "fanout",
    "CELERY_DEFAULT_RATE_LIMIT": null,
    "CELERYD_POOL_PUTLOCKS": true,
    "CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER": "json",
    "CELERYD_WORKER_LOST_WAIT": 10.0,
    "CELERYD_POOL_RESTARTS": false,
    "CELERY_TASK_PUBLISH_RETRY": true,
    "CELERY_ENABLE_UTC": true,
    "CELERY_SEND_EVENTS": false,
    "BROKER_CONNECTION_MAX_RETRIES": 100,
    "CELERYD_LOG_FILE": null,
    "CELERYD_FORCE_EXECV": false,
    "CELERY_CHORD_PROPAGATES": true,
    "CELERYD_AUTOSCALER": "celery.worker.autoscale:Autoscaler",
    "CELERYD_STATE_DB": null,
    "CELERY_ROUTES": null,
    "BROKER_HEARTBEAT_CHECKRATE": 3.0,
    "CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT": [
        "json"
    ],
    "BROKER_LOGIN_METHOD": null,
    "BROKER_CONNECTION_RETRY": true,
    "CELERY_TIMEZONE": null,
    "CELERYBEAT_MAX_LOOP_INTERVAL": 0,
    "CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL": "WARN",
    "CELERY_REDIRECT_STDOUTS": true,
    "BROKER_POOL_LIMIT": 10,
    "CELERY_SECURITY_CERT_STORE": null,
    "CELERYD_CONSUMER": "celery.worker.consumer:Consumer",
    "CELERY_INCLUDE": [],
    "CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD": null,
    "CELERYD_LOG_FORMAT": "[%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s/%(processName)s] %(message)s",
    "CELERY_ANNOTATIONS": null,
    "CELERY_MESSAGE_COMPRESSION": null,
    "CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS": false,
    "CELERY_QUEUES": null,
    "CELERY_ACKS_LATE": false,
    "CELERYMON_LOG_FORMAT": "[%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s] %(message)s",
    "BROKER_HOST": null,
    "CELERY_EVENT_QUEUE_TTL": null,
    "BROKER_FAILOVER_STRATEGY": null,
    "CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND": "djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend",
    "CELERY_BROADCAST_EXCHANGE": "celeryctl",
    "CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE": null,
    "CELERYD_TIMER": null,
    "CELERY_RESULT_DBURI": null,
    "CELERY_DEFAULT_DELIVERY_MODE": 2,
    "CELERYBEAT_LOG_LEVEL": "INFO"
}
```

Comment: having same issue. would really like to know whats going on or how to find what causes this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure if this is an answer, but here are a few things I've learned.

First, here is my Heroku procfile:

```
web: gunicorn my_app.wsgi
celery: celery worker -A my_app -l info -c 3 --beat -b amqp://K5r-y7B1:1xxxxxxxi44x6j6PgfOJcWUksQ-Qyw1@yellow-thistle-3.bigwig.lshift.net:10653/kbOAUITC91D
```

Second, Heroku actually runs this celery worker in a multi-threaded fashion.  This is different from my dev setup.  The upshot is that on dev jobs run one after the other, but on Heroku a long job will not prevent a shorter job from running.  Basically, Heroku loads multiple instances of the app into memory, whereas on dev only one instance is loaded at a time.

Third, this may not be a memory leak, precisely.  From my understanding, nothing bad happens until memory use exceeds 400%.  In any case, my app has been running for months with this warning continually occurring but without any negative effects.

Answer (score 0):

There is celery inspect command called `objgraph` that can generate chart for the memory auditing. You need to pip install `objgraph` first and then run:

```
celery -A Project inspect objgraph
```

https://javier.gr/blog/2014/04/python-reference-leaks-and-objgraph/
https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3436